# How to find Fourier sine series of $f(x)=x(1-x), 0\lt x \lt 1$?

Tags: fourier-series

How to find Fourier sine series of $f(x)=x(1-x), 0\lt x \lt 1$?

This is not an odd functions, so how to proceed?

Comment: You have to extend it to $[-1,1]$ so it is an odd function.  So that $f(-x)=-f(x)$.   Then just calculate the fourier coefficients using the usual formulas.

Comment: How to extend it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(x)=f(x)$ where $0<x<1$ and $g(x)=-f(-x)$ for $-1<x<0$.  Then $g$ is an odd function.  So you have to expand $g$ and that's the same as expanding $f$ in a sin series.

Comment: Why expanding g will be same as expanding f ?

Comment: Because in $(0,1)$ which is the domain of $f$ the two functions are equal.

Comment: And since $g$ is an odd function you know expanding it will automatically produce a sin series.

Comment: Okie.
And for calculating $b_n$ , coefficient of series, we need to integrate from 0 to 1 , right ?

Comment: I believe you need to integrate from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: But also since $g$ is odd, $g(x)\sin(nx)$ is even and so the integral from $-1$ to $1$ is just $2$ times the integral from $0$ to $1$.  So in effect you do only need to integrate from $0$ to $1$, just make sure to multiply by two.

Comment: @Member FYI it's customary to up-vote and/or hit the check mark when somebody gives you a proper answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry sir for the delay, I will be upvoting your answer for sure. I am in hurry to submit the assignment so, I thought to complete that first.

Comment: @Member Thanks wasn't trying to rush you.  Just saw that you are relatively new here so just wanted to make sure you knew the drill.  Good luck with the assignment.

Comment: Also one more thing, it's probably easier to calculate the series for $x$ and $x^2$ separately, and then just subtract, than to do $x-x^2$ in one fell swoop.

Comment: I have done it sir, Thanks for your help.